# How to show the output in textarea when using $('div') and CSS (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea

When I use this codes, it Prints the result in a new html page, how can I print the results in a nominated textarea? lets I want the result to be shown in: bookForm.myText.value

Update: PLEASE NOTE ONLY THE bTitle IS SUPPOSED TO BE ITALIC

**HTML:**

```
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
span{
    font-style: italic;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
bTitle = bookForm.txtTitle.value;
bName = bookForm.txtName.value;
bNumber = bookForm.txtNumber.value;

var concatBook = "<span>"+bTitle+"</span> by "+bName+" sold "+bNumber+" Copies."
$('div').html(concatBook);
```

Answer (score 3):

Add Textarea in with id "mytext"

```
     <textarea id="mytext" name="somename"></textarea>
```

Add Javascript

```
      bTitle = bookForm.txtTitle.value;
      bName = bookForm.txtName.value;
      bNumber = bookForm.txtNumber.value;

      var concatBook = ""+bTitle+" by "+bName+" sold "+bNumber+" Copies.";
      $('#mytext').val(concatBook);  //this will display result in textarea
      $('#mytext').css('font-style', 'italic');
```

Comment: Thanks mate, the only problem it has is that it makes all the output in mytext in italic whereas only bTitle (book title) should be in italic

Comment: For these cases,  you have to use text editors.
like wysiwyg html editor, ckeditor.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1
*Create a textarea with id, here id is "myTextarea"*

```
    <textarea id="myTextarea" name="somename"></textarea>
```

Step 2
Javascript

```
    bTitle = bookForm.txtTitle.value;
    bName = bookForm.txtName.value;
    bNumber = bookForm.txtNumber.value;

    var concatBook = ""+bTitle+" by "+bName+" sold "+bNumber+" Copies.";
    $('#myTextarea').val(concatBook);  //this will display result in textarea
```

Comment: Thanks but that defeats the purpose of me wanting to display the book title (bTitle) in italic

Comment: then instead of displaying it in a textarea, try displaying inside a "div". Thus you will get italics,bold anything you want :)

Comment: I am new to programming in JS, so not very good at div, all I want is to show that concatBook in a box, whether a text box or a texarea or whatever. but the does I have above completely wipe the page and show the output only without GUI i created